# Creating sObject via REST - date format

Tags: rest-api, date

Currently, I've used the postman to make a request to standard Saleforce API.
At the Date field I inputted year only.
[image]
As I expected, that should be inserted fail for that case.
But actually, the record inserted successful. And I've taken a look at the date field, it populated the first day of inputted year.

[image]
That's so strange.
As I known that salesforce API allow only the input date with format: **yyyy-MM-dd**.
I tried to research why but no luck.
Could anyone give me an explanation or related document about this??
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Edit: As I suspected, the JSON parser used by the REST API allows extra formats that are not documented in the documentation. It is strongly recommended that you use only the documented date format specification (YYYY-MM-DD).

---

The SOAP API specifically requires (YYYY-MM-DD) for date fields. For the REST API, you can use (almost?) any ISO 8601 format, including such options as:

| Format | Example | Note |
| --- | --- | --- |
| YYYY | 2022 | Assumes Jan 1st (1/1/2022) |
| YYYY-MM | 2022-07 | Assumes first day of month (7/1/2022) |
| YYYY-MM-DD | 2022-07-09 | n/a |
| YYYY-Www | 2022-W27 | Returns Monday of that week (7/4/2022) |
| YYYY-Www-D | 2022-W27-6 | 1=Monday, 7=Sunday (7/9/2022) |
| YYYY-DDD | 2022-190 | 1=Jan 1, 365=Dec 31 in non-leap year (7/9/2022) |

I'm not entirely sure where this is called out in the documentation, however. Just be aware that you can use a variety of date formats with the REST API.

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox for the quick rep. That's make me a little bit confused. The document below point me for the require format: yyyy-MM-dd format
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/intro_valid_date_formats.htm

Comment: @DungRieu I don't know if it's documented, but I'll ask.

Comment: @DungRieu By the way, it's an undocumented feature and should not be relied on.

Comment: thanks for your great support. I've tested your table, and that's really worked as you said. But If that hasn't any official information or undocument feature. So should I think the current issue is a Salesforce's bug?

Comment: @DungRieu It's not a bug, it's an undocumented feature. For example, there is a special Apex namespace called `Apex`. It's not documented, and it only has a few classes in it. One such class in there is `Apex.Stack`, which is a First-In, Last-Out buffer implementation. I found it by accident once, and was similarly told not to use it, because it's not production quality, whatever the limits were. So, there are things that are in the system that are simply left undocumented on purpose. They're not bugs.

Comment: Got it. That's so clear. Thanks @sfdcfox